# Jquery Tab: Can I use Html.ActionLink to fetch server data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI 1.7/PACKT book. It said on p.63 that the content of a page can be loaded just by using this statement

```
<li><a href="tabContent.html">AJAX Tab</a></li>
```

How can I obtain something with **Html.ActionLink()**

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the jQuery UI Tabs, Html.ActionLinks will work exactly the same way.  The key is to ensure that you have your unordered list items within a div tag with an id of "tabs."

Something like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Tab Name 1", "Action1", new { Controller = "ControllerName" })%></li>
        <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Tab Name 2", "Action2", new { Controller = "ControllerName" })%></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Just include this within your .aspx file that you want the tabs to appear, and make sure to include the jquery and jquery-ui scripts, and it should work for you.  You can read about the various [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) parameters by following the link. That should help you understand the ActionLink better.

Hope that helps!  Please let me know if you need any additional clarification.

Comment: What's the path? Is that the action?

Comment: @Richard77 - Sorry, yes.  That is the action. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Richard77 - What's not working exactly? Are the tabs displaying? Are the links not working (but it looks like tabs)? More details would be appreciated.